# Checkbox stops working after triggered manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I've wrote this jQuery snippet to handle `tr` click, to add a bootstrap class to it and click the first `checkbox` in it.

```
$('body').on('change', '.select-all-children', function(e) {
  var checked = this.checked;

  $('.select-child').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', checked);

    if(checked) {
      $(this).parent().parent().addClass('warning');
    } else {
      $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('warning');
    }
  });

});

$('body').on('click', '.table-selectable tbody tr', function(e) {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('.select-child');

  checkbox.click();

  var checked = checkbox[0].checked;

  if(checked) {
    $(this).addClass('warning');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('warning');
  }
});

$('body').on('change', '.select-child', function(e) {
  var checked_total = $('.select-child:checked').length;

  if(checked_total == $('.select-child').length) {
    $('.select-all-children').prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    $('.select-all-children').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Whenever I click on the `tr` and thus trigger this call:

```
checkbox.click();
```

I cannot click on the checkbox no more, but the `tr` click works fine.

This is my HTML markup of the table:

```
<table class="table table-selectable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" class="select-all-children">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="select-child">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it more simply than your method, just like this:

***Handling Select All checkbox:*** *( will just check/uncheck the FIRST checkbox in rows, and adding `warning` class to selected rows ).*

```
$('.select-all-children').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('tr td:first-child input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);

    if (this.checked){
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').addClass('warning');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr').removeClass('warning');
    }
});
```

***Handling clicks on the tr:*** *( also we can using `toggleClass` instead of `add/remove class` ).*

```
$('.table-selectable tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('warning');
});
```

Now see [***JsFiddle DEMO***](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/9jLf9pga/), *I hope it works for you, Thanks.*

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the code like this and the checkbox works fine. Please see the change in JQuery code with comments.

$('body').on('change', '.select-all-children', function (e) {
            var checked = this.checked;

```
        $('.select-child').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', checked);

            if (checked) {
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass('warning');
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('warning');
            }
        });

    });

    $('body').on('click', '.table-selectable tbody tr', function (e) {
        var checkbox = $(this).find('.select-child');

        //Old code commented:
        //checkbox.click();

        //Modified Code:
        checked.click();

        var checked = checkbox[0].checked;

        if (checked) {
            $(this).addClass('warning');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('warning');
        }
    });

    $('body').on('change', '.select-child', function (e) {
        var checked_total = $('.select-child:checked').length;

        if (checked_total == $('.select-child').length) {
            $('.select-all-children').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('.select-all-children').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does not work. You cannot call a function on something that's undefined - `checked` in this case.